# Unable to install Visual C++ Build Tools, A setup package is either missing or damaged

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to install [Visual C++ Build Tools](http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools). But while installing I keep getting this error during setup
`A setup package is either missing or damaged`

I even tried copying respective package from VS Enterprise edition to the path but it keeps repeating this error. I also tried selecting download package option but no gain.

[image]

Comment: To find the root cause of this issue, you need to use http://aka.ms/vscollect to gather the installation logs. After using it, you will find vslogs.zip under %temp% folder, then upload the file to https://onedrive.live.com/ and share the link here.

Comment: Have you installed the VS enterprise 2015 before?Because these components that includes in the Visual C++ Build Tools 2015 are the same as the ones installed by the Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 setup, you cannot install the Visual C++ Build Tools on a machine that already has Visual Studio 2015 installed. For the detail information, see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/03/31/announcing-the-official-release-of-the-visual-c-build-tools-2015/?__hstc=268264337.0ba69fbd4700abf2f6b07d4fdafcc3eb.1478771705914.1478771705914.1478851750849.2&__hssc=268264337.1.1478851750849&__hsfp=4077456719

Comment: If you have not install the VS enterprise 2015, make sure windows update is up-to-date, temporarily disable any antivirus software, clean up the %temp% folder and re-run the installer as administrator. If this issue persists, you can collect and share your installation logs. you can go to Control Panel—Programs and Features and right click the VS 2015 item and Change-Modify, then check the option of those components that relates to the Visual C++ Build Tools, like Visual C++, Windows SDK… then install them.

Comment: @Sara : i have the same problem; in my log (you can find it here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1XFlitR9p0RRFVBU1lEQUJ3WU0) there's an error about downloading the package (Error 0x80190193: Failed to download BITS job). I manually downloaded the file, using the url in the log, but the installer then give me another error: "Microsoft Build Tools 14.0 (x86) : A certificate chain could not be built to a trusted root authority."

Comment: @dipanda, I found several error messages in your log and it looks like your issue is not the same with Maven, you can create a new thread with your detail information and the complete installation log (the vslogs.zip), then add tag with visual-studio-2015, installation, I will continue to research your issue. Meanwhile, you can have a try with my preview comments that I mentioned before, and output the result in your new thread.

Answer (score 28):

I think you might have Installed the MS BUILD TOOLS after DOWNLOADING it from the following LINK

http://download.microsoft.com/download/5/F/7/5F7ACAEB-8363-451F-9425-68A90F98B238/visualcppbuildtools_full.exe

I did the same and got the same ERROR

INSTALL using the following LINK

https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/confirmation.aspx?id=48159

Comment: Thanks! Still working in 21 for people interested!

Comment: alleluiha it works, thank you very much Sai, you save my time.

Comment: Thankyou, this works!

Answer (score 0):

In my case using Windows 7 I had accidently disabled some services for better performance. I used:

```
net start bits
net start msiserver
```

and it worked